# Laravel PDF creation Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I made a pdf creator link in my laravel app. But when i click on my link to the PDF i get a 404. This is my code:

Link to the customer:

```
<a href="/mvs/mvs/public/admin/kunden/pdf/{{ $kunden->id }}">Button html</a>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/mvs/mvs/public/admin/kunden/pdf/{id}', 'DynamicPDFController@get_customer_data');
```

PDF Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use PDF;

class DynamicPDFController extends Controller
{
function index()
{
 $customer_data = $this->get_customer_data();
 $finance_data = $this->get_finance_data();
 return view('dynamic_pdf')->with('customer_data', $customer_data);
}

function get_customer_data($id)
{
//Handle PDF stuff here 

$customer_data = DB::table('kundens')
 ->where('id', '=', $id)
 ->firstOrFail();

//Save PDF link to customer here

 $customer_data->save();
 return $customer_data;
}

function pdf()
{
 $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
 $pdf->loadHTML($this->convert_customer_data_to_html());
 return $pdf->stream();
}

function convert_customer_data_to_html()
{
 $customer_data = $this->get_customer_data();
 $output = '
 <h3 align="center">Angebot</h3>
 <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px;">
  <tr>
<th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="20%">Vorname</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="30%">Nachname</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="15%">Stadt</th>
<th style="border: 1px solid; padding:12px;" width="15%">PLZ</th>
```

';
      foreach($customer_data as $kunden)
     {
      $output .= '
      
       '.$kunden->vorname.'
       '.$kunden->nachname.'
       '.$kunden->wohnort.'
       '.$kunden->plz.'

The complete routes:

```
Route::get('/mvs/mvs/public/admin/kunden/pdf/{id}', 

'DynamicPDFController@get_customer_data');


Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('admin/kunden', 'KundenController');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/dynamic_pdf', 'DynamicPDFController@index');

Route::get('/dynamic_pdf/pdf', 'DynamicPDFController@pdf');
```

When i now click on the link "Button HTML" i get a 404 error page. But i dont know why :(

**UPDATE:**

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::save()
```

Thats the new Error - i edit the route to the answer.

Comment: Does your other route work? your route and url look strange to me.

Comment: Yes - the other routes work fine. /mvs/mvs is just the local folder structure :)
I can post the complete routes - wait

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your route to this:

```
Route::get('/admin/kunden/pdf/{id}', 'DynamicPDFController@get_customer_data');
```

(Same as your other route)

I think your index.php file is located at `/mvs/mvs/public/` so Laravel will only get the route from there.

Comment: This was for the Error - but now i got a new one:
Call to undefined method stdClass::save()